# Content security policy including a gumroad script

Tags: content-security-policy

I am developing a website with Wordpress that includes a Gumroad script, in the console it throws the following error:

> extended_bundle-2dd0f46384e8ed974d932b1190b99d42941abe18a7b69f4e8bd492fa0a309a13.js:1 Refused to connect to 'https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j87&tid=UA-29108090-1&cid=256380548.1611057176&jid=2069832337&gjid=1027868402&_gid=88988440.1611562559&_u=SCCAiEADRAAAAE~&z=875389156' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' bam.nr-data.net [www.dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com) s3.amazonaws.com/gumroad s3.amazonaws.com/gumroad/ [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com) *.facebook.com *.facebook.net files.gumroad.com/ d1bdh6c3ceakz5.cloudfront.net/ *.braintreegateway.com [www.paypalobjects.com](http://www.paypalobjects.com) *.paypal.com *.braintree-api.com iframe.ly gumroad.com".

I tried to fix it by putting the info in the meta, but I'm sure I'm wrong. what is the best solution to fix this? (I have never faced this problem before).

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https 'self'; child-src * data: blob:; connect-src 'self' bam.nr-data.net www.dropbox.com s3.amazonaws.com/gumroad s3.amazonaws.com/gumroad/ www.google.com www.gstatic.com *.facebook.com *.facebook.net files.gumroad.com/ d1bdh6c3ceakz5.cloudfront.net/ *.braintreegateway.com www.paypalobjects.com *.paypal.com *.braintree-api.com iframe.ly gumroad.com; font-src * data: blob:; frame-src * data: blob:; img-src * data: blob:; media-src * data: blob:; object-src * data: blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ajax.cloudflare.com static.cloudflareinsights.com js.stripe.com api.stripe.com *.braintreegateway.com *.braintree-api.com www.paypalobjects.com *.paypal.com www.google-analytics.com *.g.doubleclick.net optimize.google.com www.googleadservices.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com *.facebook.net *.facebook.com *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net www.dropbox.com s.ytimg.com *.jwpcdn.com content.jwplatform.com/libraries/3vz4Z4wu.js *.jwpsrv.com blob: 'self' data: gumroad.us3.list-manage.com analytics.twitter.com 'sha256-VM/GRb7zfHAoT0vOuAlUed7we+jp8z0wsVKkGxFFsqI=' gumroad.com assets.gumroad.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' s.ytimg.com ssl.p.jwpcdn.com optimize.google.com assets.gumroad.com; worker-src * data: blob:">
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to fix it by putting the info in the meta, but I'm sure I'm wrong.

To fix the issue you have to add `https://stats.g.doubleclick.net` host-source to `connect-src` directive.

It's 2 ways to publish CSP:

1. via meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">`
2. via HTTP header `"Content-Security-Policy: ..."`

Avoid to use both ways at the same time - in case of 2 CSPs the rules will join with logical "AND" and you'll failed to get expected result.

Therefore you need to know in which way your Wordpress publish the CSP, and then to add the `https://stats.g.doubleclick.net` into meta **OR** into HTTP-header respectively.

Typically WP uses plugins to publish CSP. It can also be published in the `.htaccess` file.

**Note 1**: the console error you described could be not yours if you use iframe with third-party content (some external widgets, Google auth etc.). Because browser use one console to display CSP violations in any iframes.
Moreover, you could have installed some browsers plugins which tries to modify the viewed page. This can cause CSP violations too.

But lookes like it's caused by Google Adsense you place in web page. `https://stats.g.doubleclick.net. is used to collect stat of Google Ads.